# Update and log out Android

Tags: android, session, logout

i have a question: is there a possibility that , when i send a new update of my app in the Google Play Store and the user install it, to log out his/her app session? (this means to send him/her directly to the Log In screen)

I have this function for Log out:

```
public void logoutUser() {
    pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    editor = pref.edit();
    editor.clear();
    editor.commit();
    alarmMgr = (AlarmManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent alarm = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AlarmReceiver.class);
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, alarm, 0);
    alarmMgr.cancel(pendingIntent);
    Intent intent = new Intent(Activity3.this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Thanks :)

Comment: listen to broadcast MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED and do the logout in the broadcast receiver

Comment: Hi @TimCastelijns thanks for the answer. Can you explain a little more about this option? thanks!

Comment: you can just google it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An options is to use your version code of the app

```
import com.yourpackage.BuildConfig;
...
int versionCode = BuildConfig.VERSION_CODE;
```

When your app starts, check your SQLite db or SharedPreferences for your version number, if it's not there or it's lower, the app has been updated, store the new version number and log the user out. Check if the current versioncode is higher than the stored one each time the app starts.

From https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element.html

> android:versionCode
>
> An internal version number. This number is used only to determine whether one version is more recent than another, with higher numbers indicating more recent versions. This is not the version number shown to users; that number is set by the versionName attribute.
> The value must be set as an integer, such as "100". You can define it however you want, as long as each successive version has a higher number....

Comment: seems a bit over complicated when there is a builtin broadcast that just tells you when an update has happened

Comment: Could be, it's just an option

Comment: Thanks so much for answering i will try it! :)